# What does "/mnt/dir" mean here?

Tags: mount, disk-image

I am trying to recover data from my hard drive and then mount it, with the first part I have cleared up more or less, I will do it with **ddrescue**, with the second not so much ... I [found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316407/374478) a solution to mount, but I have some difficulties to understand it:

```
losetup -f # this will print the first available loop device ex:/dev/loop0
losetup /dev/loop0 /path/file.iso #associate loop0 with the specified file
mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/dir #It may be necessary specify the type (-t iso9660)
```

My problem is with last line:

```
mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/dir #It may be necessary specify the type (-t iso9660)
```

The question is with **dir**, what would it mean to say here, my **iso** image or the name that I would give it, or is it a file that the person does not say, I have to do it before, for example with `sudo mkdir /mnt/dir`

Please explain my mistake in easy words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is with "dir", what would it mean to say here, my "iso" image or the name that I would give it, or is it a file that the person does not say, I have to do it before, for example with `sudo mkdir /mnt/dir`

"/mnt/dir" is not the ISO image or disk image.  "/mnt/dir" needs to be an empty directory.

Your Linux install should have created "/mnt" as an empty directory.  It is meant to be used for temporary mounts like this.  If "/mnt" is empty, you can just use "/mnt".

Sometimes "/mnt" might not be empty.  For example, if you have directories inside it like "/mnt/usb" and "/mnt/dvd".  If so, then you can create an empty directory for example with `sudo mkdir /mnt/recover`.  Then you can use the directory you created in the `mount` command.

Comment: Very Thanks for your answer!, you think on the answer from a0f3dd13 should i create this directory ?

Comment: ....and very Thanks for my English correction..

Comment: @dsaj34v If `ls /mnt` shows there are no files or directories in `/mnt`, you could use `/mnt`. But, you can create `/mnt/dir` or for example `/mnt/recovery` instead if you like.  Creating and using `/mnt/dir` should not cause any problem.

Comment: thanks!, I wish your a nice Day!

Comment: @dsaj34v The words "recover my hard drive" suggest you are not having a very good day.  But I wish you a good one too!

Comment: Thanks for the correction , I don't knew it...because my English is very Bad , I use the Tool grammarly and some time it not working very well..