# How to used losetup with two external hard disks

Tags: mount, usb, hard-disk

sorry for my English...

I rescue data(Films) from a external hard disks with **ddrescue**. The file name is **rescue.img** and it is stored on an external hard disk.

Now I will mount **rescue.img** as [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316407/374478) to say,

`losetup -f 
 losetup /dev/loop0 /path/rescue.img 
 mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/dir`

Because my **rescue.img** has 2TB and my external hard disk has only 3TB, I will it to mount to other external hard disks.

My question, how to mount my **rescue.img** to the other external hard disk?

Can Please someone to explain to me, how to does it with easy words, Thanks!

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to understand .... a mount point is not really attached to a hardware disk

Comment: very thanks for you answer!  and how mount a point the other hard disk?