# How to append files to an image file and deploy it with `dd` to a device?

Tags: linux, raspbian, dd

[EDIT: simplified and corrected]

I would like to use the same method as Raspbian install which relies on `dd` deployment to a µSD. Meaning, from a minimal image file, deploy the "augmented" Raspbian system partitions with `dd` on a SD card, resulting into two partitions and their files.

Is there a way to augment (inject files) the image blob file?

(The augmented image file won't fit into RAM)

Comment: I think the easiest way is to install it i a fast SD card, do some tweaks and then clone it to an image file. Otherwise, to create an own operating system (maybe call it re-spin) is *a rather big task*. You could do it [from scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) using an existing system in your computer. There are also some shortcuts, but I have no own experience from doing it in an RPi.

Comment: thank you @sudodus, I will do the simple way for now. The only optimization I can think of is to use a 8GB µSD, so that the `dd` won't take very long. Otherwise, I studied 4 scenarios: `dd` with partitions, ramfs, whole disk 'dd' containing the required partitions, `dd` extended partition containing required partitions. None can work for several reasons. It is a bit too long to give details.

Comment: actually, I would like to modify the blob image file, as you can do it for .iso files using a software. You can open the .iso and add/delete files. Would it be also possible with a `dd` image of the µSD card?

Comment: If you don't want to work with the system on a real drive (µSD card), you might be able to work with it in a virtual machine with a virtual disk (for example using VirtualBox). I think it is possible to edit an image in a file directly, it the file system is writable, but I have not worked that way, and cannot give any detailed warnings and tips.

Comment: @sudodus well, that would not be suited for my use case. I'm looking for an industrialized process, using few and swift steps. The process would be: start with a deployed Rasbian on a µSD card >---> `dd` to Desktop (one image file or partitions) >---> adding files to it on Desktop >---> 'dd' back to a new µSD : fully working augmented Raspbian

Comment: I have seen some website suggesting to use `losetup` or `kpartx` to mount partititions with file systems in image files. It might work for you (but I have no own experience). Search the internet for `linux mount disk image`

Comment: well done @sudodus! `loop` setup is a great deal of the solution! I could map both Rasbian partitions to loop partitions. Then I can add files, and `dd` back to an empty µSD. The only problem which remains si the loop disk size. I can't find a way to increase it. Decrease is documented otherwise. I will first write the answer and open a new question for loop size increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sudodus helped me find the answer.

How to augment the image? -> mount the image file as loop disk/partitions. Use a mounting point. Add the files.
For details: [another loop question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316401/how-to-mount-a-disk-image-from-the-command-line)

How to use `dd` to write the augmented image to another µSD?

`sudo dd bs=4M status=progress of=/dev/sdf if=/dev/loop1 conv=fsync`

Answer (score 0):

```
# losetup -fP image.img
```

-f will set it to the first loop device

-P will make a partition table

The device will be called /dev/loop0

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange, and thanks for your first answer. However, it is not clear how your suggestion adds anything to the other answer.