# mount: operation not permitted (WSL2 running Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: ubuntu, mount

I am trying to mount this raspberry pi image for qemu to `/mnt/raspbian` but the mount command gives error:

```
root@ubuntu-wsl:/mnt/raspbian# sudo mount -v -o offset=70254592 -t ext4 qemu_vms/2017-01-11-raspbian-jessie.img /mnt/raspbian
mount: /mnt/raspbian: mount failed: Operation not permitted.
```

Comment: please try answers here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/316401/72456 and feedback the result by [edit]ing your question

Comment: i actually dont know anything about that. I am using this tutorial to run raspbian on qemu -> https://azeria-labs.com/emulate-raspberry-pi-with-qemu/

Comment: Hang on. That tutorial is about running raspbian in a virtual machine (VM). Are you using a VM or are you running these commands on WSL? The tutorial clearly states: "Inside your Ubuntu VM, create a new folder:" and all other commands need to be run from inside the VM.

Comment: uhh... i am running those from wsl

Comment: Then please follow the instructions you linked to and run them in the VM instead.

Comment: okay i guess i am too dumb. i didnt even read that article fully.